# sending two php variables to function from array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an AJAX function called search that receives the ID and the srcpath, which then sends the two variables to a PHP script that unlinks the image and deletes the file directory from the DB. I've attempted to do this with the following, however I keep getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .'

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete' onclick='search(".$fetch['id'].", ".$fetch['srcpath'].")'/>";
```

Comment: What is `$fetch['srcpath']`?  It probably needs to be quoted.

Comment: It returns this (from the console): onclick='search(86, ./userimages/Screen Shot 2015-05-09 at 15.09.06.png)'

Comment: @TomReeves As you pasted, you need to add some quotes to your second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$fetch['srcpath']` is a string so you need to quote it:

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete'
       onclick='search(".$fetch['id'].", \"".$fetch['srcpath']."\")'/>";
```

Maybe better like this:

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete'
       onclick='search({$fetch['id']}, \"{$fetch['srcpath']}\")'/>";
```